# Updating a database with simple php and mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a VERY simple form that is not working. What I am trying to accomplish is when the user clicks the update button, they are presented with a form filled in with the information. When they change the information and click update, they are sent back to the main form with all of their changes presented. Everything works but the update. When you change something and click update, nothing is changed. Here is the update form code:

```
<h4>Update Record</h4>
<?PHP
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "customers");

//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
 }
 ?>
 <form action="update_process.php" method="get">
   Band: <input type="text" name="artist" value="<?php echo $_GET['artist'] ?>"/><br/>
   Album: <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $_GET['title'] ?>" /><br/>
   Format: <select name="format">
      <option value="Compact Disc" name="compact disc">compact disc</option>
      <option value="Album" name="album">album</option>
      <option value="Cassette" name="cassette">cassette</option>
      <option value="MP3" name="mp3">mp3</option>
       </select><br/>
    Notes: <TEXTAREA NAME="notes" ROWS="3" COLS="30"><?php echo $_GET['notes'] ?>
      </TEXTAREA><br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Update" />
   </form>
```

And here is the code for the update_process.php file:

```
 <?php
 $artist = $_GET['artist'];
 $title = $_GET['title'];
 $format = $_GET['format'];
 $notes = $_GET['notes'];

 //create connection to DB
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "customers");

  //check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

  $sql = "UPDATE music SET title='$title', artist='$artist', format='$format', notes='$notes'
     WHERE id='$id'";

  if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     header('Location:index.php');
   } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: Any errors in the log?

Comment: Are you saying the database information is not being updated, or that the information in your form is not updated? Also, if you not using binds with mysqli you are vunerable to SQL injection (e.g. I put ''; DROP TABLE customers;--` as the artist name you would lose your customer table.

Comment: @JayBlanchard First thing I look for, then I keep moving further down.

Comment: Space in `name="compact disc"` so that will break your code, yet it's still invalid; options don't have `names` only the select.

Comment: Plus, as noted in answers below, `$id` is undefined, which is only part of the problem. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, which it **will**.

Comment: You wouldn't get anything from that code if it were a parse error. You would only recieve something from that code for parse errors if you put it in a seperate file then included the bad file.

Comment: You can't update something with no id. You need to retrieve the id first

Answer (score 1):

In the WHERE clause you says where id = '$id', but where is the $id value set? 
I think $id does not have a value.

Comment: He has a point. It's part of the problem @JayBlanchard yet not the full answer.

Comment: Too many problems, so little time. And no response from the OP. :-/

Comment: @JayBlanchard Exactly and all the more reasons I chose to stay far away from this one. Commenting usually gets to the heart of the problem.

Comment: Yes I am trying to use the ID field as a reference for the update. Have to figure out how to get id

Comment: @Fred-ii-I am "she" :)

Comment: @carito I stand corrected. Sorry about that :) was hard to say. I should have written `he/she` just to be safe. Is it Spanish?

Comment: @Fred-ii- carito comes from Carolina, and yes it is Spanish. Don't worry, It is not very common to see a female programmer here :)

Comment: @carito That's what I thought; it resembles Italian, a language I speak, amongst a few lol I know a bit of Spanish though. Those resemble each other a lot.

Comment: @Fred-ii-Italian! nice.

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems with your code:

1 - where id `$id` defined?

2 - I guess id is an integer field, so the `'`s around `$id` are not needed;

Comment: It's  only part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've mixed object based and function based programming. You started with function based, so I'll show you that way. To query a database, you need to run:

```
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Rather than:

```
$con->query($sql)
```

There are a few other problems security wise with your code, but skip the rest of my answer if you don't care.

You're not checking to see whether those GET parameters exist before you use them. Use:

```
if(isset($_GET['artist'],$_GET['track'],...)) {...}
```

You're also not escaping your query strings, making your site vulnerable to SQL injection. Use:

```
$artist = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['artist']);
```

Good luck! Just go read the PHP docs, making sure you either take object or function approach for the entire script.

Comment: Please go over the comments under OP's question. I've chosen not to put in an answer. Too many things wrong with OP's code and unclear.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Yes I am new, so don't appreciate the expert harassing but that thank you